Categories internal to the category of convex sets
Let $\text{Conv}$ be the category of convex sets, as described by Proposition 1 of Jacobs. I want to understand the nature of categories internal to Conv. Any concrete description would be useful, but here are some more pointed questions:

Is there an analogue of Lemma 6, from Baez and Crans saying that composition is determined by other structure ?

Is there a free functor from Cat to the category of categories internal to Conv, that is associated with the free functor from Set to Conv ? (I'm looking for a way to gets lots of examples of internal categories of Conv).


I'm also interested in similar questions for categories internal to the Eilenberg-Moore category of the subdistribution monad.
